# Place-holders used as construct name compromise correct indentation

Tags: vim, fortran, label, indentation, placeholder

I wrote a Vim script for the autocompletion of Fortran program units, type definition and so on, taking the cue from vim-latex plugin.

At the moment, if I strike `<F5>` while the cursor is on the word `program`, I get the following

```
PROGRAM <+program_name+>           

    USE <+used_module_name+>

    IMPLICIT NONE

    <++>

END PROGRAM <+program_name+>
```

with the first `<+program_name+>` visually selected and Vim in select mode. And this is perfect for me.

The problem arises when I use such a placeholder as a label for the `IF` construct. When I expand `if` I get

```
    <+name+>: IF (<+logical expression+>) THEN
    <++> ! this line is not indented => in turn the following are negative indented
ELSE IF (<+logical expression+>) THEN
    <++>
ELSE
    <++>
END IF <+name+>
```

where the second line is not indented due to the fact (*at least I suppose!*) that the string `<+name+>` is not a valid name. As a consequence, the following lines move back (obviously when the if is in the first column, the second line is the only one to be wrong).

This also happens for the `DO` construct, but, strangely, doesn't happen for the `SELECT CASE` construct:

```
<+name+>: SELECT CASE (<+case expression+>)
CASE (<+case selector+>)
    <++>   
CASE DEFAULT
    <++>   
END SELECT <+name+>
```

And this is why I think a soultion must exist and be not so complicated.

Comment: It might be a better idea to consider one of the existing snippet solutions, such as [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips).  The [vim-snippets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets) collection of snippets can be used with it, and it has a snippet for Fortran.

Comment: I think I correctly installed UltiSnips, since `:help UltiSnips` works, but I didn't manage to install vim-snippets.

Comment: Why do you think you didn't manage to install `vim-snippets`?  Unlike other plugins, `vim-snippets` is only data it doesn't "do" anything.

Comment: So what should I do after download the zip file from the second link in your comment? Manually copy the files? If so, where should I put them?

Comment: You need to install it just like any other plugin (hopefully you're using a plugin manager for that).  Then you'll need to read the docs for `UltiSnips` to put everything together.

Comment: I'll try on my laptop in the evening. On the Mac from which I'm writing right now I have Vim 7.3.x, which is not enough to install UltiSnips.

Comment: I think now UltiSnips is installed on my laptop, but there must be some interference with the mappings to jump back and fort through placeholders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to solve the problem in the "dirty" way, that is, by inserting spaces in proper position in the command sequence generating the the `IF...THEN...ELSE...END IF` and `DO...END DO` constructs. This is not an elegant solution, but I don't think that has so much drawbacks. The only thing to change would be the number of spaces to add manually to the command sequences according to `shiftwidth`.

As @SatoKatsura suggested in a comment, it'd be better to abandon this road and use existing snippet solutions.